# Why can't I terminal stop after my gulp process finishing

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gulp

I want to apply react to my NodeJs

This is my gulpfile:

```
let gulp = require('gulp');
let uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
let browserify = require('browserify');
let babelify = require('babelify');
let source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
let buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
let gutil = require('gulp-util');
let sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
let assign = require('lodash.assign');
let watchify = require('watchify');


let customOpts = {
    entries : ['./App/app.js'],
    extensive : ['.js'],
    debug: true
};

let opts = assign({}, watchify.args, customOpts);
let b = watchify(browserify(opts));

gulp.task('js', bundle); // so you can run `gulp js` to build the file
b.on('update', bundle); // on any dep update, runs the bundler
b.on('log', gutil.log); // output build logs to terminal

function bundle() {
    return b.transform(babelify,babelify.configure())
        .bundle()
    // log errors if they happen
        .on('error', gutil.log.bind(gutil, 'Browserify Error'))
        .pipe(source('app.js'))
        // optional, remove if you don't need to buffer file contents
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
}
```

gulp.task('default',['js']);

Then I intput gulp js

```
D:\weather-app>gulp js
[00:03:47] Using gulpfile D:\weather-app\gulpfile.js
[00:03:47] Starting 'js'...
[00:03:57] 2112196 bytes written (10.56 seconds)
[00:04:27] Finished 'js' after 41 s
```

The terminal got stuck here, I had to type Ctrl C to stop it.

Strangely, when I opened the index.html, the appearance changed.

So I don't know how could that be.

Comment: migrate to webpack.

Comment: Thank you very much. I 've tried to use Webpack, but it still needs me to take a long time to config it. Then, I want to try gulp to pack them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS Code, you may use the Run On Save extension which will run your gulp task on every file save, so you do not need to kill the Terminal process and run your gulp command repeatedly.  Here's the link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave

After installing the extension, add the following code to your workspace settings.json. In this example, the command to run on file save is simply "gulp."

```
"emeraldwalk.runonsave": {
    "commands": [
        {
            "match": ".*",
            "isAsync": true,
            "cmd": "gulp"
        },
    ]
}
```

In my case, I use Gulp and BrowserSync to compile HTML files and refresh the browser automatically, so running "gulp" and CTRL-C over and over in the Terminal was getting annoying.